# how to use liner gradient and radial gradient both at a time in highcharts?

Tags: javascript, highcharts, linear-gradients, radial-gradients

I am making highcharts theme for my project, i have to use gradient color for pai and bar chart, so i  am putting  below code into my theme.js file

```
Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {
        return {
            linerGradient:{x1:0,x2:0,y1:1,y2:0},
            radialGradient: {
                cx: 0.5,
                cy: 0.3,
                r: 0.7
            },
            stops: [
               [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
            ]
        };
```

here it is getting only radialGradient even my  bar chart is getting radialGradient only..! how can i make it work according to the graphs? i want to make it globally.Link to put it in theme.js file.

Is it possible to capture chart type ? so that i can use if condition and make it up..! 

thanks in advance ..!!!

Comment: Could you post your concept how it should look like? I mean graphically, what is an idea to use both of them at the same time?

Comment: I have pai chart and bar chart in the same page. So i need to  use both..!
I cant send gradient in series, because i am taking only data from controller and putting into my custom directive. so i need some thing global.

Comment: To do that, define two separated colors (as gradient) per each series. http://jsfiddle.net/npq3Lt1p/

Comment: Sebastian i know this way, but i don't want to give dependency at the data side. I have a custom directive which accepts the data from the service and append it to series.data. And from the backend i get only data points, so i need some thing global one....!!! please let me know if you did not get it properly ..!!!!!

Comment: @SebastianBochan I need something like this, but this is not working..!

`code`Highcharts.getOptions().colors = Highcharts.map(Highcharts.getOptions().colors, function (color) {

if(Highcharts.getOptions().type=="pie"){
        return {
            radialGradient: {
                cx: 0.5,
                cy: 0.3,
                r: 0.7
            },
            stops: [
               [0, color],
                [1, Highcharts.Color(color).brighten(-0.3).get('rgb')] // darken
            ]
        };
} else{
 return {
 linerGradient:{x1:0,x2:0,y1:1,y2:0}
}
}
`code`

Comment: @SebastianBochan I will add the above code in theme.js file..!

Hope you got it :)

Comment: You can catch the callback or [load event](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#chart.events.load) iterate on each element and apply color by [point.update](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock#Point.update)

Comment: @SebastianBochan i did not get you, could you please brief me your idea..!